# Sms retriever API can't get sms info with starting with \u200b\u200b

Tags: android, api, google-api

I am using Google newly launched Sms Retriever API and it works fine when i receive message like this **<#>code:32343 xxxxxxxxxxx** but it doesn't work message like this **\u200b\u200bcode:32343 xxxxxxxxxxx** on my real device (htc one) it is weird that everything work fine on virtual device, so can you guys tell me what's wrong with my device?

API: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/

Comment: same here, but not work with release apk :T

Answer (score 2):

According google, the message need to fullfill following requirements:

- Begin with the prefix **<#>**

Your "\u200b\u200b" is not the same, so it will not work obviously

See also:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify

Comment: According to [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/googles-sms-retriever-api-6540eb3c8e9c) article, The message could start with any of the following: <#> or Two consecutive zero-width space characters (U+200B). So I can understand the confusion. Was it possible before? is the article simply outdated?

Comment: Alright, I just tested on an emulator and real device and \u200b\u200b does work for me. Just remember that the message itself has to be short, if it's more than a couple of words it might be too long and will not be registered.